# how to get float rounding mode for c/c++ in vs2008/2012/2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, floating-point, rounding, mode

My problem is as follows:

I need  to know the current floating-point rounding mode for c/c++ programs in  present vs2012 /2010/2008 developing environment . Set the rounding mode (_RC_NEAR,_RC_DOWN,...) by calling _set_controlfp(_RC_DOWN,_MCW_RC), and default is _RC_NEAR. However, I want to get the value;

I try to call _statusfp() get the return value, but in which rounding mode did not store , the return value is always 0 unless an inaccuracy arithmetic(such as , overflow etc.) and is not dependent on rounding mode. After reading  float.h supplied by vs2012/2008, I also cannot find any tips.

Comment: Q: Does this link help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9st43tcf.aspx?

Comment: Probably this helps, there is an example on C


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867693/change-floating-point-rounding-mode

Comment: @Dumanskiy  . It  is ok ! . by calling _controlfp(0,0) , I know this function, but did not  known the arguments. Thanks.