# Round Down a Floating Point Result

Tags: c, floating-point, double, rounding

I have two floating point (double) values *a* and *b*, and I'm looking to add them to get a result *c*.

I know that *c* will somehow be approximated, because everything is finite precision. Now, I want to 'round down' *c*, meaning that the floating point *c* is not greater than the real sum of floating points *a* and *b*, or *c* <= *a* + *b*.

How can I do this? The following code in c comes to mind, but I'm not sure whether the answer will be what I want.

```
c = nextafter(a + b, bigNegativeNumber)
```

Same question goes for multiplication instead of addition. :)

PS. If it helps, *a* and *b* are always non-negative numbers.

Edit: *c* should be a floating point as well

Comment: if c is integer type then you can just cast

Comment: At least on some architectures you may be able to set the rounding mode to round towards zero or negative infinity: `IEEE 754 1985: 4.2. Directed Roundings
An implementation shall also provide three user-selectable directed rounding modes: round toward +INFINITY, round toward – INFINITY, and round toward 0.`

Comment: Same as Weather Vane, but the longer route, `c = floor(-1 * (a + b))*-1`; if there was some issue with decimal rounding.

Comment: @user3528438 it is floating point type, not integer. If it were integer there would be no question to begin with.

Comment: @WeatherVane I edited the post, I'm interested in finding a floating point value, not an integer one. Sorry for being vague.

Comment: If I previously misunderstood your question, I think you will find that any lack in precision will result in `c` being always `<= a + b` when `a` and `b` are positive.

Comment: @WeatherVane: ...unless the floating-point implementation is in round-to-nearest- or round-towards-(positive-)infinity-mode?

Comment: @WeatherVane ah I misread, now looking, also wondering how two positives could be negative, if added.

Comment: @EOF: Looks like what I'm looking for. I found a how-to at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867693/change-floating-point-rounding-mode)

Thanks!

Comment: @EOF thanks yes, just been looking at MSVC `_control87` which can specify a flag `_MCW_RC` for Rounding control. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e9b52ceh.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, it seems like you want to control the rounding mode for a floating-point operation. This is supported in C99 by the functionality provided in the header file `fenv.h`. You may need to instruct your compiler to turn on C99 support, and you may need to instruct it to perform floating-point arithmetic in an IEEE-754 compliant way. Below is a minimal example showing how to perform `double` addition with truncation (rounding towards zero). Since your operands are known to be positive, this is equivalent to rounding down (towards negative infinity).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fenv.h>

#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON

double dadd_rz (double a, double b) 
{
    double res;
    int orig_mode = fegetround ();
    fesetround (FE_TOWARDZERO);  // set rounding mode to truncate
    res = a + b;
    fesetround (orig_mode);      // restore rounding mode
    return res;
}

int main (void)
{
    double a = 0x1.fffffffffffffp1023;
    printf ("                  a = %20.13a\n", a);
    printf ("                a+a = %20.13a\n", a + a);
    printf ("round_to_zero (a+a) = %20.13a", dadd_rz (a, a));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The output of the above program should look something like this (note that the printing of infinities is implementation dependent):

```
                  a = 0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023
                a+a = 0x1.#INF000000000p+0
round_to_zero (a+a) = 0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023
```

Answer (score 0):

A tricky problem.

[@EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3185968/eof)'s comment above to "round toward 0" is good and will provide an optimal result.

```
#ifdef _ _STDC_IEC_559_ _ 
    fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);
    c = a + b;
#else
   #error unable to set rounding mode
#endif
```

OP's original approach is close too.  Any good compilation/processor should be expected to create the best answer to with in 0.5 or 1.0 ULP (depending on rounding mode).  It will certainly create a sum `c2` less than arithmetic `a+b`, but `c` *may* meet the requirements too.

```
c = a + b
c2 = nextafter(c, -DBL_MAX);
```

`c = floor(a + b)` will not work as `a` could be far larger in magnitude than some small negative `b` such that the computed sum is simple still `a` and fails the *arithmetic* `c <= a + b`.