# Ensure float to be smaller than exact value

Tags: c++, floating-point, rounding, precision, floating-point-precision

I want to calculate a sum of the following form in C++

```
float result = float(x1)/y1+float(x2)/y2+....+float(xn)/yn
```

xi,yi are all integers. The result will be an approximation of the actual value. It is crucial that this approximation is smaller or equal to the actual value. I can assume that all my values are finite and positive.
I tried using nextf(,0) as in this code snippet.

```
cout.precision( 15 );
float a = 1.0f / 3.0f * 10; //3 1/3
float b = 2.0f / 3.0f * 10; //6 2/3
float af = nextafterf( a , 0 );
float bf = nextafterf( b , 0 );
cout << a << endl;
cout << b << endl;
cout << af << endl;
cout << bf << endl;
float sumf = 0.0f;
for ( int i = 1; i <= 3; i++ )
{
    sumf = sumf + bf;
}
sumf = sumf + af;
cout << sumf << endl;
```

As one can see the correct solution would be `3*6,666... +3.333.. = 23,3333...`
But as output I get:

```
3.33333349227905
6.66666698455811
3.33333325386047
6.66666650772095
23.3333339691162
```

Even though my summands are smaller than what they should represent, their sum is not. In this case applying `nextafterf` to `sumf` will give me `23.3333320617676` which is smaller. But does this always work? Is it possible that the rounding error gets so big that `nextafterf` still leaves me above the correct value?

I know that I could avoid this by implementing a class for fractions and calculating everything exactly. But I'm curious whether it is possible to achieve my goal with floats.

Comment: IEEE754/floats are subject to rounding and representation errors. If you absolutely need exact values consider using fractions or arbitrary precision numeric types.

Comment: Set the rounding mode to `FE_DOWNWARD` and then do your calculation.  Or `nextafterf(foo, -1.0/0.0)` your calculation 2n-1 times.

Comment: @RegretBomb: It's like you didn't even bother reading the question...

Comment: @tmyklebu Slightly redundant text doesn't mean I didn't read your question.

Comment: @RegretBomb It's like you read so little that you didn't even see that the asker and the person telling you that your remarks are irrelevant are different persons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My immediate reaction is that the approach you're taking is fundamentally flawed.

The problem is that with floating point numbers, the size of step that `nextafter` will take will depend on the magnitude of the numbers involved. Let's consider a somewhat extreme example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

int main() { 
    float num = 1.0e-10f;
    float denom = 1.0e10f;

    std::cout << std::setprecision(7) << num - std::nextafterf(num, 0) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::setprecision(7) << denom - std::nextafterf(denom, 0) << "\n";
}
```

Result:

```
6.938894e-018
1024
```

So, since the numerator is a lot smaller than the denominator, the increment is also much smaller.

The result seems fairly clear: instead of the result being slightly smaller than the input, the result should be quite a bit larger than the input.

If you want to ensure the result is smaller than the correct number, the obvious choice would be to round the numerator *down*, but the denominator *up* (i.e. `nextafterf(denom, positive_infinity)`. This way, you get a smaller numerator and a larger denominator, so the result is always smaller than the un-modified version would have been.

Comment: plus one but mention interval arithmetics at the end?

Comment: Interesting behaviour! Not sure if I understand your point, though. num and denom are always integers in my case.

Comment: @Ricardo: I used floats for a simple example, but you can get exactly the same situation when the inputs are integers.

Answer (score 5):

Try changing the float rounding mode to FE_TOWARDZERO.

See code example here:

[Change floating point rounding mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867693/change-floating-point-rounding-mode)

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Some values are still rounded to infinty. I read that  `#pragma STDC_FENC_ACCESS` is compiler-dependent.  May this be the issue here? I'm using gcc 4.8.4.

Comment: Setting the rounding mode worked as `fegetround` gives another result than before. But sadly this does not affect the result of the rounding.

Comment: @Ricardo I get the sum 23.3333327770233 - is the posted code 100% identical to your running code?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I removed the `nextafterf` function calls believing that the rounding will do what they did. If I keep them, I get a smaller result.  But why is summing affected by the rounding type, but not divisions of the form `2.0f/3.0f` ?

Comment: @Ricardo: Most compilers will do constant folding in round-to-nearest by default.  You need to specify `-frounding-math` with gcc (`#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON` does *not* do the trick).  I'm not even certain that `-frounding-math` completely works...

Comment: @tmyklebu -  true - it doesn't seem to work for all tool chains. I did some testing using different systems/tools and the result wasn't entirely as I expected. Anyway this was the best proposal I had. Do you know of a better solution? Despite the up-votes I got, I have a feeling that my answer doesn't cover the question entirely....

Comment: @StillLearning: I don't know a better solution for people who want directed rounding.  It's unfortunate that compiler vendors don't care about implementing their languages correctly, and it's also unfortunate that there's no real recourse besides whining like me on the Internet if you haven't got several months to learn a compiler's internal workings well enough to contribute.  But that seems to be how life currently is.

Comment: Changing the mode to `FE_TOWARDZERO` fails when converting `y1` to `float` results in a smaller value than the  mathematically exact result.  Using this smaller `y` value in the division could result in a larger than exact  quotient and then not meet "approximation is smaller or equal to the actual value".

Answer (score 0):

`float result = float(x1)/y1+float(x2)/y2+....+float(xn)/yn` has 3 places where rounding may occur.

1. Conversion of `int` to `float` - it is not always exact.
2. Division `floating point x/floating point y`
3. Addition: `floating point quotient + floating point quotient`.

By using the *next*, (either up or down per the equation needs), the results will certainly be *less* than the exact mathematical value.  This approach may not generate the `float` *closest* to the exact answer, yet will be close and certainly smaller.

```
float foo(const int *x, const int *y, size_t n) {
  float sum = 0.0;
  for (size_t i=0; i<n; i++) {  // assume x[0] is x1, x[1] is x2 ...
    float fx = nextafterf(x[i], 0.0);
    float fy = nextafterf(y[i], FLT_MAX);
    // divide by slightly smaller over slightly larger
    float q = nextafterf(fx / fy, 0.0);
    sum = nextafterf(sum + q, 0.0);
  }
  return sum;
}
```