# Using fenv.h in MinGW

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, fenv

I want to change a floating-point rounding mode using standard library as suggested in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867693/change-floating-point-rounding-mode) and [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/fenv/feround). I use MingGW as an envirement. CMake is used to build of the project. My code:

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <fenv.h>

#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON
void show_fe_current_rounding_method(void)
{
    printf("current rounding method:  ");
    switch (fegetround()) {
           case FE_TONEAREST:  printf ("FE_TONEAREST");  break;
           case FE_DOWNWARD:   printf ("FE_DOWNWARD");   break;
           case FE_UPWARD:     printf ("FE_UPWARD");     break;
           case FE_TOWARDZERO: printf ("FE_TOWARDZERO"); break;
           default:            printf ("unknown");
    };
    printf("\n");
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(test)

SET(GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-std=c++11 -march=native -mavx")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
```

However, the following errors are occur during the compilation:

```
error: 'fegetround' was not declared in this scope...
error: 'FE_TONEAREST' was not declared in this scope..
error: 'FE_DOWNWARD' was not declared in this scope...
error: 'FE_UPWARD' was not declared in this scope...
error: 'FE_TOWARDZERO' was not declared in this scope...
```

That is the content of `<fenv.h>` is not available in my code (the condition `#if _GLIBCXX_USE_C99_FENV_TR1` in `\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\fenv.h` does not satisfied). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please edit your question and remove the pictures of text. Instead add the actual text. Also show your output and what output you expect. Right now it is unclear what exactly is the question.

Comment: I don't use MingGW, but I've used CMake and a Linux toolchain a bit. Maybe try changing your variable `GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS` value to `-std=c++11` seeing that `<fenv.h>` is a `C++11` feature ?

Comment: @PrimRock Unfortunately, it did not help.

Comment: In C++, use `#include <cfenv>` and `std::` namespace prefix.

Comment: Try what @DaBler said and use `#include <cfenv> ` and see what happens

Comment: @DaBler `#include <cfenv>` and  `std::` produced no result, since `MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\cfenv` also has the condition `#if _GLIBCXX_USE_C99_FENV_TR1`. [See image](https://s16.postimg.org/ww41vm82d/image.png)

Comment: @KonstantinIsupov: Is the `_GLIBCXX_USE_C99_FENV_TR1` macro defined in your `bits/c++config.h` (look for it in the mingw32 directory)?