# How to correctly floor the floating point pair sum

Tags: c++, c, floating-point

Let me have two floating point variables coming as function arguments:

```
float fun(float x, float y) {
     // ...
}
```

I would like to calculate the floor of their sum. Is it possible to do it correctly not relating on current floating point rounding mode?

I mean the following. Consider the expression:

```
floorf(x+y)
```

It is possible that the exact value of the function argument (x + y) < n for some integer n will be rounded to the nearest integer n during the floating point operation, and then the floorf() function will return n instead of (n-1).

Comment: It should be sufficient to set the *rounding mode* to round downwards for the addition...

Comment: `sum = x + y; error = sum - (abs(x) > abs(y) ? x : y) - (abs(x) > abs(y) ? y : x); sum = error > 0 ? nextafter(sum, 0) : sum;` (the error computation for other operations is mentioned in Handbook of Floating-Point Arithmetic)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a demonstration using the numbers given by Bathsheba and the effect of [the floating point rounding mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867693/change-floating-point-rounding-mode):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fenv.h>
#include <math.h>


int main(void) {
    double y = 0.49999999999999994;
    double x = 0.5;


    double z1 = x + y;

    // set floating point rounding downwards    
    fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);

    double z2 = x + y;
    printf("y < 0.5: %d\nz1 == 1: %d\nz2 == 1: %d\n", y < x, z1 == 1, z2 == 1);
    printf("floor(z1): %f\nfloor(z2): %f\n", floor(z1), floor(z2));
}
```

`y` is less than 0.5, so the sum of y + 0.5 should be less than 1, but it is rounded to 1 using the default mode (`z1`). If the floating point rounding mode is set to round downwards, the result is less than 1 (`z2`), which would floor to 0. Clearly it is not possible to do this "correctly" under "any arbitrary floating point rounding mode"...

The output is

```
y < 0.5: 1
z1 == 1: 1
z2 == 1: 0
floor(z1): 1.000000
floor(z2): 0.000000
```

Comment: What does fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD) do internally? How long does it usually take to switch round mode (measured, say, in CPU cycles)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible.

A well-known example is an IEEE754 64 bit `float` (unusual but possible by the standard)

`x = 0.5` and `y = 0.49999999999999994`.

`(x + y)` is exactly 1 and yes `floorf` will return 1.

Comment: (I can't think of any examples in 32 bit IEEE754, but I can't see why there aren't any. You could test with a 2D algorithm using `nextafter`)