# How to change the rounding mode for floating point operations in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, floating-point, rounding

I want to change the rounding mode for floating point operations in MATLAB. According to IEEE 754-2008, there are 5 strategies for rounding:

- round to nearest, ties to even
- round to nearest, ties away from zero
- round toward zero
- round up (toward positive infinity)
- round down (toward negative infinity)

Does MATLAB supports these 5 strategies? How to change the rounding mode for floating point operations in MATLAB?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, but I might be wrong about that. The documentation doesn't even mention which of the modes is used.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes, it's very strange that as a numerical computing software, MATLAB doesn't tell users about the rounding modes it supports.

Comment: MATLAB does not support these 5 strategies. MATLAB simply use the strategy which is set in your processor (FPU). There are ways to change it but you'll have to use something closer to the metal, like `C` code (don't know if you can do it through `mex`). Inspiration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867693/change-floating-point-rounding-mode) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/control87-controlfp-control87-2?view=vs-2019).

Comment: @Hoki Thanks for your reply, I have already learned to change rounding modes in ```C``` language. Do you know any numerical computing softwares that support different rounding modes?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *the rounding mode for floating-point operations*? Which operations? Can you show an example?

Comment: @nekomatic You can have a look at IEEE 754-2008 Std and you will understand what I'm saying.

Comment: I know about the standard thanks, I wanted to see an example of the actual operations you're doing, what result you get and what result you would like to get. Then someone might have information to help you.

Comment: What's your use case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Answer

Kind of. There is an undocumented `feature('setround')` function call that you can use to get or set the rounding mode used by Matlab.

So, it can be done, but you shouldn’t do it. :)

> WARNING: This is an undocumented, unsupported feature! Use at your own peril!

This `feature('setround')` supports 4 of the 5 IEEE-754 rounding modes: there’s only one “nearest” mode, and I don't know if it’s “ties to even” or “ties away from zero”.

Supported modes:

- `feature('setround')` – Get current rounding mode
- `feature('setround', 0.5)` – Round toward nearest (don’t know if it’s ties to even or away from zero)
- `feature('setround', Inf)` – Round up (towards +Inf)
- `feature('setround', 0)` – Round toward zero
- `feature('setround', -Inf)` – Round down (towards -Inf)

Note on testing: The IEEE-754 rounding mode does not affect `round()` and its relatives. Rather, it governs how arithmetic operations behave around the limits of floating-point precision.

### Demonstration

```
%ROUNDINGEXAMPLE Demonstrates IEEE-754 Rounding Mode control
%
% This uses a completely undocumented and unsupported feature!
% Not for production use!

%% Setup
clear; clc

n = 2000;
X = ones(n)*1E-30; % matrix with n^2 elements
defaultRoundingMode = feature('setround'); % store default rounding mode

%%
feature('setround',0.5);
r1 = prettyPrint('Nearest', sum(X(:)));
%{
  sign   exponent                       mantissa
     0 01110110001 0011010101111100001010011001101001110101010000011110
     | \_________/ \__________________________________________________/
     |      |             ______________________|___________________________
     |      |            /                                                  \
(-1)^0 2^( 945 - 1023) 1.0011010101111100001010011001101001110101010000011110 = 4e-24
%}

%%
feature('setround',-Inf);
r2 = prettyPrint('To -Infinity', sum(X(:)));
%{
  sign   exponent                       mantissa
     0 01110110001 0011010101111100001010011001101001011100000111000110
     | \_________/ \__________________________________________________/
     |      |             ______________________|___________________________
     |      |            /                                                  \
(-1)^0 2^( 945 - 1023) 1.0011010101111100001010011001101001011100000111000110 = 4e-24
%}

%%
feature('setround',Inf);
r3 = prettyPrint('To Infinity', sum(X(:)));
%{
  sign   exponent                       mantissa
     0 01110110001 0011010101111100001010011001101010100011101100100001
     | \_________/ \__________________________________________________/
     |      |             ______________________|___________________________
     |      |            /                                                  \
(-1)^0 2^( 945 - 1023) 1.0011010101111100001010011001101010100011101100100001 = 4e-24
%}

%%
feature('setround',0);
r4 = prettyPrint('To zero', sum(X(:)));
%{
  sign   exponent                       mantissa
     0 01110110001 0011010101111100001010011001101001011100000111000110
     | \_________/ \__________________________________________________/
     |      |             ______________________|___________________________
     |      |            /                                                  \
(-1)^0 2^( 945 - 1023) 1.0011010101111100001010011001101001011100000111000110 = 4e-24
%}

%%
feature('setround',defaultRoundingMode);
r5 = prettyPrint('No accumulated roundoff error', 4e-24);
%{
  sign   exponent                       mantissa
     0 01110110001 0011010101111100001010011001101010001000111010100111
     | \_________/ \__________________________________________________/
     |      |             ______________________|___________________________
     |      |            /                                                  \
(-1)^0 2^( 945 - 1023) 1.0011010101111100001010011001101010001000111010100111 = 4e-24
%}

%% Helper function
function r = prettyPrint(s, r)
    fprintf('%s:\n%65.60f\n\n', s, r); 
end
```

I get:

```
Nearest:
   0.000000000000000000000003999999999966490758963870373537264729

To -Infinity:
   0.000000000000000000000003999999999789077070014108839608005726

To Infinity:
   0.000000000000000000000004000000000118618095059505975310731249

To zero:
   0.000000000000000000000003999999999789077070014108839608005726

No accumulated roundoff error:
   0.000000000000000000000003999999999999999694801998206811298525
```

### Acknowledgments

Thanks to Ryan Klots at MathWorks Technical Support for setting me straight on this and providing the nice demo code!

Comment: Amazing solution! Actually I'm designing a hardware single-precision floating point unit (FPU), and the FPU is required to support the 5 rounding modes in IEEE 754-2008. Therefore I want to use MATLAB to generate some test data for different situations, which is more convenient than writing C codes.

Comment: One more question, I run ```help feature``` in MALTAB ternimal but get no return information. What else can I do by using this function ? I'm also wondering why MATLAB doesn't describe this function in the documents. I think it is very important for users like me who really care about the ```LSB``` of the floating point number.

Comment: That's because `feature()` and its friend `system_dependent()` are the gateway to Matlab's *undocumented*, *unsupported*, *user-beware* functionality. Matlab leaves them undocumented intentionally to discourage their use. If you want to learn more about them, you want @yair-altman's [Undocumented Matlab](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/) site: https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/undocumented-feature-function, https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/undocumented-feature-list.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm gettin' my money's worth from my Matlab license this week.

Comment: Hi, I find that MATLAB uses ```round ties away from zero```. However it dosen't support ```round ties to even```. So MATLAB supports 4 of 5 rounding modes described in IEEE 754-2008. Run ```int32(single(X.5))``` in MATLAB will return X + 1.```int32(single(0.5))``` returns 1, and ```int32(single(1.5))``` returns 2. I think the reason is that most back end computations in MATLAB are written in C and C++. At present, C and C++ only supports 4 rounding modes except ```round ties to even```. So MATLAB just does the same.

Comment: Thanks HYF! That makes sense. Yeah, Matlab is built on BLAS/LAPACK/Intel MKL/etc, which are written in C/C++ and a lot of Fortran.

Comment: I can confirm that this works for Matlab '9.5.0.1033004 (R2018b) Update 2'. Moreover, the change in rounding mode affects both scalar instructions such as $y=1+2^(-52)$ and matrix matrix operations such as $y=(1+2^-52)*ones(8,8); y=y.^2$. It appears likely that MATLAB changes the rounding mode for both scalar and SIMD operations. Regardless, +1 for a excellent answer which was most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

@HYF: I found that feature('setround', 0.5) leads to round to even.
I checked the following:
`a=1+2^-52`
This means that mantissa looks like so: `1.0...01` where the last 1 is still in the mantissa. The leading 1 is not stored in IIIE754 format.
( I checked that `1+2^-52 == 1` but not  `1+2^-53 == 1`)

Then I computed `b = a + 2^-53`.
Without rounding it is `1.0...01|1` where the last digit is to be rounded away.
I found the following true: `b==1+2^-51`
We have `b == 1.0...010`.

We have several rounding modes submodes of round to nearest:
This can be round to inf, round away from 0 or round to even.

Next we check  `-b==-1-2^-51` to be true which excludes round to inf
still allowing round away from 0 or round to even.

Then I checked `1.5==1.5+2^-53`.
Of course `1.5 = 1.10...0` binary and
and `1.5+2^-53 = 1.10...0|1` without rounding, the last digit to be rounded away.
Rounding away from 0 would be `1.10...01`
and rounding to even is `1.10...0`.
So the latter is the case.