# Floating point multiplication on VC++ 2008 express

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008

why the following snippet

```
int i = 30;
int p = 0.7f * i;
printf("p is %d\n", p);
```

gives 20 instead of 21 on vc++ 2008 express ?
I know it's an old compiler!

Comment: The value `0.7` cannot be exactly represented in a floating point variable. Please see [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) and [Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate) Note that `20.999999` will be truncated to `20`.

Comment: Thank you for the links, but I was more curiose about what Microsoft should have changed in VC++ 2019, because it give the correct mathematical result.

Comment: Do you mean with that *exact code*, or when you `printf` the floating point value? Perhaps 2008 had a slightly different floating point implementation.

Comment: good point! But I do not printf the floatint point value, it is already casted to int. I think I can answer myself looking at assembler produces by both compilers.

Comment: Perhaps the older PC uses an 80x87 FPU. The point is, you not should rely on accuracy from floating point arithmetic.

Comment: Please see [Change floating point rounding mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867693/change-floating-point-rounding-mode) and MS [_control87](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/control87-controlfp-control87-2?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number 0.7 is not representable in the binary-based floating-point format your compiler uses for `float`. When the decimal numeral “0.7” is converted to `float`, the result is the nearest representable value. That is a number slightly below 0.7.

Multiplying that by 30 produces a number slightly below 21, and converting it to `int` with truncation produces 20.