# Why is the result of the C program showing a different result than expected?

Tags: c

When I run this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
    float x;
    double y;
    x = - 2147483645.0;
    y = -2147483645.0f; 
    printf("%f, %f", x, y);
return 0;
}
```

the result is -2147483648.000000, -2147483645.000000

Why is it so?`

Comment: Can't reproduce it on debian (gcc-10)

Comment: A `float` has less bits for it's mantissa (significant digits) than a `double`.

Comment: Here is a good paper: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: BTW you have the data type specifiers the wrong way round. A decimal value is `double` so it is the `float` initialiser that needs the `f` suffix.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between float and double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386772/what-is-the-difference-between-float-and-double)

Answer (score 4):

Floating points are imprecise, and having a larger size means more precision. In this case, a `double` is large enough to precisely store the number, but a `float` isn't, which means it prints out as the wrong value. [Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7644699/how-are-floating-point-numbers-stored-in-memory).

Comment: Wrong implies an error has occurred. The value isn't wrong.  It's the closest float.

Answer (score 4):

The value `2147483645.0` would be `1.111111111111111111111111111101∙2³⁰`
in binary form, so it needs a 30 bit mantissa. But the `float` data type offers only a 23 bit mantissa while `double` has around 52 bits. The sign is saved separately (this also depends on your plattform and your compiler, this values are for standard x86).

Consider this program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  float x = -2147483645.0;
  double y = -2147483645.0;

  printf("%f  %X\n", x, *((unsigned*) &x));
  printf("%f  %X%X\n", y, *( ((unsigned*) &y)+1), *((unsigned*) &y));
}
```

I compiled it with gcc 5.4.0 for x86 and get as output:

```
-2147483648.000000  CF000000
-2147483645.000000  C1DFFFFFFF400000
```

The internal format of the numbers in hexadecimal notation can be seen on the right:

```
float x (32 bits in total):
===========================
Sign:     1
Exponent: 100 1111 0 (bias 127 + 31)
Mantissa: 000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000

double y (64 bits in total):
============================
Sign:     1
Exponent: 100 0001 1111 (bias 1023 + 32)
Mantissa: 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

I have grouped the numbers here as in the output. The double `y` stores exactly the binary representation of the number as described above. In contrast, the mantissa is zero for the float `x`. This is because the bits are not simply cut off. Instead, the value is rounded depending on the excess bits. That's why you got `1.0∙2³¹=2147483648` as in the output.

You can also try this out on sites like [these](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html).

The rounding is done by the c preprocessor here. I don't know a way to influence this, but you can control the rounding mode within the programm, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867693/change-floating-point-rounding-mode):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fenv.h>
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON

int main() {
  float x;
  double y = -2147483645.0;
  
  fesetround(FE_TONEAREST);
  x = y;
  printf("FE_TONEAREST:  %f %X\n", x, *((unsigned*) &x));
  
  fesetround(FE_UPWARD);
  x = y;
  printf("FE_UPWARD:     %f %X\n", x, *((unsigned*) &x));
  
  fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);
  x = y;
  printf("FE_DOWNWARD:   %f %X\n", x, *((unsigned*) &x));
  
  fesetround(FE_TOWARDZERO);
  x = y;
  printf("FE_TOWARDZERO: %f %X\n", x, *((unsigned*) &x));
}
```

Compile with `-lm` option. This outputs

```
FE_TONEAREST:  -2147483648.000000 CF000000
FE_UPWARD:     -2147483520.000000 CEFFFFFF
FE_DOWNWARD:   -2147483648.000000 CF000000
FE_TOWARDZERO: -2147483520.000000 CEFFFFFF
```

Comment: So if it uses a 23 bit mantissa then I presume it would save the first 23 bits and each of them would be 1. And when we transform that number (1.11111111111111111111111 * 2^30) into its decimal equivalent we would get 2147483520. Why isn't that the result?

Comment: I've added some further explaination to the post: The excess bits aren't just cut off. The value is rounded depending on this bits so you got `1.0∙2³¹=2147483648` (and it's `2³¹` instead of `2³⁰`, my mistake)

Comment: You were right the first time - it is 1.111111111111111111111111111101∙2^30, not 1.111111111111111111111111111101∙2^31. I think I finally got it. Mantissa has 23 bits but if we need more than that, you need to check the 24th bit that you would put if you had a 24 bit mantissa. If that bit is 0, then you do nothing. You have your 23 bit mantissa. But if it is 1, then you need to add 1 to the whole mantissa just like when doing addition with binary numbers.

Comment: And because of that, my logic is  (cosidering the number in my example) that you have: 1.1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 111 + 0.0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 001 and that is 10.00000000000000000000000 * 2^30 or 2^31 and that is our number. You actually need to add 1 to the whole mantissa including the hidden bit.

Comment: After doing some further research, I can say that the rule I mentioned in the previous comment doesn't work. It does somehow round the bits in mantissa but I don't get the rule. Any idea how rounding really works?

Comment: The rule seems to be "round to nearest" here, but this is done by your compilers preprocessor. I've added another code example to the post.