# is there a way to round down float type in c++?

Tags: c++11, printf, rounding

How could I round down float type variable? (using `printf`)

```
for example,  
float x = 3.35;  
printf("%.1f", x);
```

In this situation, it will print out 3.4 but i want it to print 3.3.
Is there any way to do it? (without using `trunc` or `floor` function)

Comment: `printf("%.1f", static_cast<int>(x*10.f) / 10.f);`

Comment: `printf("%.1f", x-0.05);`

Comment: Related and/or possible duplicate for changing the rounding mode generically: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6867693/10871073

Comment: Are you aware that `3.35` cannot be represented exactly in binary? It's approximated as 3+1/4+1/16+...

Comment: What's wrong with `floor()` and `trunc()` ?  They exist for a reason.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy: They'd round to `3.0f`, not `3.3f` for starters. And that's not simply solved by a `/10.0f` because `3.3f` cannot be represented in binary, unlike `3.0f`.

Comment: @MSalters  `printf("%.1f", floorf(x*10.f)/10.f));` is the usual way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

No, you can't change the rounding mode of `printf`. It's implementation-defined.

Comment: Yes you can ([`fesetround`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/fenv/feround)), and it's standard since C99 and C++11.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I double-checked C99, and it just describes the `%f` format as "The value is rounded to the appropriate number of digits." in the _normative_ text. But "correctly rounded." is listed as a _recommended practice_, `fesetround` exists, but whether it accepts the requested "round down" mode depends on `FE_DOWNWARD` - which is implementation-defined.