# At C++, how can I drop after second decimal places without using 'floor' function?

Tags: c++, decimal, rounding, drop

If, there is a project that you can only use '%.nf', or 'casting' to limit the value.
How can you drop(not rounding) after second decimal places?

Comment: *How can you drop(not rounding) after second decimal places?* -- Good luck when you are trying to fix that odd case where it doesn't work, and in trying to fix it, you break something else.  Just giving you a warning when trying to finagle with floating point data.

Comment: Are you cropping the number, internally, or do you want to display the number with only 2 digits after the decimal point?

Comment: This recent question seems to be the same: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71557221

Comment: `((int)(x*100))/100.0` - it's more a math question, isn't it?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I want to display with only 2 digits after the dimicial point.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Oh WOW THANKS!!!!! Thanks so much!!!!!! I LOVE U sweet honey!!!!

Comment: See `std::set_precision` to control the output format for floating point values.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews `std::setprecision` will round the result.

Answer (score -1):

`((int)(x*100))/100.0`

How does it work?

`x*100` moves the 2 digits from behind the decimal point to in front of the decimal point.

`(int)` makes the floating point value an integer, dropping all remaining decimal digits.

`/100.0` moves the last 2 digits to behind the decimal point, where they were before.

Note that due to the IEEE-754 way of how floating point numbers are stored internally, the actual floating point number may not have exactly 2 digits after the decimal point.

Comment: @Sebastian: as per OPs question: "drop(not rounding)", so I chose not to round.