# Does _RC_NEAR use 'ties to even' or 'ties away from zero' rounding?

Tags: c++, rounding, ieee-754

I am looking for documentation that clarifies which [IEEE 754 rounding mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Rounding_rules) the Visual Studio (2022) C++ compiler uses when the `_RC_NEAR` flag is used to switch floating-point rounding modes.

[This MS doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fp-specify-floating-point-behavior?view=msvc-170#floating-point-rounding-modes) shows examples for switching rounding to + and - infinity, along with specifying the default rounding method (turns out it is `_RC_NEAR` if you look in `float.h`), but I can't find any more detail about `_RC_NEAR`, if that corresponds to *ties to even* or *ties away from zero*, as mentioned on the wikipedia page.

Comment: not exactly a dupe but has what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6867722/4342498

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks - it's buried in the comments, and then I found it in the fine print of the wikipedia page - the default is *supposed to be* **ties to even** so I guess I'll trust that the MS engineers did that, but it would have been nice to see that explicitly in the docs.