# Floating point serialization/parsing rounding

Tags: c++, floating-point, rounding

I have the following floating point number stored in memory (`float`, not `double`)

```
0b00111101111001000010000111001000
```

which, according to [floating-point-converter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) converts to

```
0.111392557621002197265625
```

I serialize it, rounding up to the 9th digit, and storing it as the following string:

```
0.111392558
```

I understood that, if now I parse the string, I'm using using [stof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof), I should expect some precision loss, which would imply that I'm not guaranteed that the parsed value would result in the original value, that is

```
0.111392557621002197265625
```

The fact is that I'm doing some unit testing and I consistently find that my expectations never met, original and parsed values are always the same.

Are my expectations right?

Comment: if you want us to explain why your unit tests pass you need to show us your unit tests. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Where the code? I suspecct you have used `flaot` type which precision is 7 decimal digits.

Comment: @MarekR yes, that's correct, I'm using floats.

Comment: If you're only storing the first 9 decimal places, try it with much smaller numbers, e.g. 0.00000..... If you're storing 9 sig. figs. then you might have to test millions of cases to find one that doesn't get back to the original value. I don't think it's safe to assume it would always get back to exactly the original value.

Comment: @SimonGoater looks like you do not understand how floating point values are working. Even `float` type can store very small values with 6-7 decimal digits of precision. Limit is range of exponent value then you have underflow values (smaller precision but not zero yet).

Comment: @MarekR Err, yes I do thanks.

Comment: @SimonGoater If I understand correctly, the fact that storing 9 significant digits with floats makes very difficult to obtain a different value when parsing because there are not much numbers in the vicinity of the parsed one? Your suggestion I suppose is due to the fact that small numbers have greater resolution, is that correct?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/bKrrh5ME8 here is nice [talk from Stephan Lavavej](https://youtu.be/4P_kbF0EbZM) with all needed details.

Comment: My point was about your float -> string function. Does it take 9 sig. figs. or 9 decimal places? When I first read you question I thought you meant decimal places. You can also play with the rounding mode https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867693/change-floating-point-rounding-mode to try to get differences.

Comment: @SimonGoater decimal places, sorry.

Comment: `The fact is that I'm doing some unit testing and I consistently find that my expectations never met, original and parsed values are always the same.`  You should show actual code of unit test. What are you using? gtest? Catch2? boost::Test? ...? All of this libraries have proper tools to handle floating point values.

Comment: @MarekR My question is more a theoretical one, about if my expectations were right and why. The unit test is not easy to run because it involves some external libraries. I found that just by chance and I asked out of curiosity. But the provided values are accurate, the memory representation is what the memory view of eclipse shows, and the string is what I get on the resulting file.

Comment: @MarekR I understand that my expectations are ok. It is not guaranteed to retrieve the original value. But depending on the value and the precision with which i store it, It may be difficult to retrieve other value than the original because there the original value is the closer one to the string representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing you mean nine significant digits, not just nine digits after the decimal point, then the farthest apart two consecutive nine-significant-digit decimal numerals can be is one part in 10<sup>8</sup>. This occurs when the first digit is 1 and the ninth digit changes by 1.

The closest together two consecutive 24-digit binary numerals can be is one part in 2<sup>24</sup>. This occurs when all the digits are 1 and we add 1 at the last digit (carrying the number up to the next power of two).

Consider, in general, rounding a number *x* to a numerical format using a round-to-nearest method. Suppose *x* is between two values representable in the format, *a* and *b*. If *a* is nearer to *x* than *b* is, we round *x* to *a*. If *b* is nearer, we round to *b*. In either case, the rounding error is less than half the distance between *a* and *b*, since we chose the nearer value. If *x* is exactly in the middle, the rounding error is half the distance. So, with round-to-nearest, the rounding error is at most half the distance between representable values. Thus, we have a Rounding Lemma: If *x* rounds to *x*', then |*x*'−*x*| ≤ ½*U*, where *U* is the distance between adjacent representable numbers bracketing *x*.

Now consider more specifically rounding a 24-digit binary numeral *x* to a nine-digit decimal numeral. Let *D* be the distance between nine-digit decimal numerals near *x*, and let *B* be the distance between 24-digit binary numerals near *x*. From above, we know *D* < *B*. Rounding *x* to a nine-digit decimal numeral yields some number *x*', and we know from the Rounding Lemma that |*x*'−*x*| ≤ ½*D*. Since *D* < *B*, |*x*'−*x*| < ½*B*. This may also be expressed as −½*B* < *x*−*x*' < ½*B*, which implies *x*'−½*B* < *x* < *x*'+½*B*.

Now let *x*'' be the number we get by rounding *x*' back to a 24-digit binary numeral. To satisfy the Rounding Lemma, |*x*'−*x*''| ≤ ½*B*, which means −½*B* ≤ *x*''−*x*' ≤ ½*B*, which implies *x*'−½*B* ≤ *x*'' ≤ *x*'+½*B*.

Now we have both *x*'−½*B* < *x* < *x*'+½*B* and *x*'−½*B* ≤ *x*'' ≤ *x*'+½*B*, which means both *x* and *x*'' are in the same interval from *x*'−½*B* to *x*'+½*B*, except that *x*'' can be on an endpoint of the interval and *x* cannot. The length of that interval is *B*, and 24-bit binary numerals are spaced *B* apart, so one of two things are true: Either there is exactly one 24-bit binary numeral inside the interval or there are two 24-bit binary numerals, one at each endpoint of the interval. The latter is impossible since then there would be no 24-bit binary numeral inside the interval to be *x*. So there is only one 24-bit binary numeral in the interval, and both *x* and *x*'' must be that numeral. Therefore *x*'' = *x*.

Thus, rounding a 24-bit binary numeral *x* to a nine-digit decimal numeral *x*' and then back to a 24-bit binary numeral must produce *x*.

Converting to an eight-digit decimal numeral is not always sufficient to restore the original 24-digit binary numeral. We can see this in several ways:

- In the interval [10, 11), there are 10<sup>6</sup>  = 1,000,000 eight-digit decimal numerals (with form 10.*dddddd*, where each *d* is any decimal digit), but there are 2<sup>20</sup> = 1,048,576 24-digit binary numerals (with form 1010.*bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb*<sub>2</sub>, where each *b* is any binary digit). Therefore, converting these decimal numerals to 24-digit binary numerals can produce only 1,000,000 results, so at least 48,576 of the binary numerals cannot be produced.
- The spacing between eight-digit decimal numerals can reach one part in 10,000,000, which is not fine enough to distinguish 24-bit binary numerals with spacings of one part in 16,777,216.
- 134,217,704 and 134,217,696 are both representable in the IEEE-754 binary32 format commonly used for `float`, and, when converted to an eight-significant-digit decimal numeral, they both round to 134,217,700, so converting back to binary can only produce one of those numbers, so one of them does not survive the round-trip.

Comment: "the farthest apart two nine-significant-digit decimal numerals can be is one part in 108.".  The smallest nine-digit number is 1.00000000, and the largest nine-digit number is 9.99999999. isn't the farthest apart  that they can be 8.99999999?

Comment: @perencia: The text is about the spacing between consecutive numerals. I edited to clarify that.

Comment: Frankly, I can't see why 10^8 is  fine enough while 10^7 is not.

Comment: @perencia: I edited to provide a semi-formal proof that converting to a nine-digit decimal numeral and back to a 24-digit binary numeral restores the original number, and I added another reason why eight-digit decimal numerals do not work.

Comment: Ok, I understand then that the relevant fact here is that with nine significant digits decimal numeral we have a resolution of one part in `10^8 (1x10^-8)`, which is a greater resolution than the one we have with a binary float `(2^24)`, which is `(~6x10^-8)`. So,
for any binary we can only have one nine-significant digit closer to it (I really appreciate your proof). With `10^7` though, its resolution is `1x10-7`, which is lower than  the one with `2^24`, so ...

Comment: ... several binaries end up in an eight significant digit representation, thus  not guaranteeing that we will recover the original when going back from the decimal representation. Does it seem ok?

Answer (score 0):

If you are converting to a decimal string like "0.111392557621002197265625" without an exponent, then 9 digits after the decimal point are certainly insufficient as the smallest positive 'normal' IEE754 single is "**0.000000000**0000000000000000000000000000117549" (0x00800000,1.17549435e-38), and Eric mentions an even smaller 'non-normal' limit in the comments, and these are distinguishable from zero.  If instead you are using an exponent in the string representation, like "1.1754944e-38" then 9 digits should be sufficient to round correctly.  This C test code (below) tests nearly all positive, non-special-case (+-Inf, Nan< Zero) IEEE754 singles.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

union fugly {
    float f;
    uint32_t u;
};


int main()
{
    union fugly before, after;
    char fstr[42];
    uint32_t i;

    for(i = 0x00800000; i < 0x7effffff; i++) {
    before.u = i;
    gcvt(before.f, 9, fstr);
    after.f = strtof(fstr, NULL);
    if( before.u != after.u  ) {
        printf("0x%08x: 0x%08x  ?=? 0x%08x\n",
           i, before.u, after.u);
        printf("          :       %.12f  ?=? %.12f\n",
           i, before.f, after.f);
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Result: (no rounding issues !)

```
$ cc -O3 float.c -o  float && time ./float

real    7m57.205s
user    7m56.574s
sys 0m0.009s
```

Reducing the string precision (argument 2 of gcvt() ,from 9 to 8 produces many rounding errors in the low bit.

```
$ cc -O3 float.c -o  float && time ./float
0x03aa242d: 0x03aa242d  ?=? 0x03aa242e
          :       0.000000000000  ?=? 0.000000000000
0x03aa2437: 0x03aa2437  ?=? 0x03aa2438
          :       0.000000000000  ?=? 0.000000000000
0x03aa2441: 0x03aa2441  ?=? 0x03aa2440
          :       0.000000000000  ?=? 0.000000000000
0x03aa244a: 0x03aa244a  ?=? 0x03aa244b
          :       0.000000000000  ?=? 0.000000000000
0x03aa2454: 0x03aa2454  ?=? 0x03aa2455
          :       0.000000000000  ?=? 0.000000000000
0x03aa245e: 0x03aa245e  ?=? 0x03aa245d
          :       0.000000000000  ?=? 0.000000000000
...
```

Of course the routines and test I am doing differs from yours, but it's not too onerous to test all single floats.

Fwiw my laptop can test all ~2^31 -(special cases) representations in ~10 minutes.   It might be worth testing your code for "corner cases".

Comment: Re “the smallest IEE754 single is "0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000049177712492031263": That is approximately 2^−150.51. That is not a representable value in IEEE-754 binary32. The smallest representable non-zero value is 2^−149 (exponent field value 1 − bias 127 = −126, first 23 bits 0, last bit at relative position −23 is 1, making −126−23 = −149), about 1.403•10^−45.

Comment: Thanks Eric.  I copied the wrong field from https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

Answer (score -3):

Well, even the website you mention shows what's going on -- but it appears you can't really understand it.

The important part is that floating point numbers are binary. In that website enter "0.5" into "decimal representation", and observe that the fields below are showing nice numbers -- no errors, binary value with lots of 0 at the end.

Now, enter "0.4" instead and observe how the other numbers are turning into a mess. Why is that?

0.5 is 1/2, or 2^-1  -- it' a power of 2, which is what binary values are all about: you need to able to express the number as a sum of such power-of-two numbers. 2^-2 would be 0.25, 2^-3 would be 0.125 -- whether or not you want to believe me, you can't get to exactly 0.4 with these numbers, hence the "mess" shown by the tool.

The important part to take home is that the fractional part of a number doesn't really work like you're used to in binary. While "1/3" in decimal produces a number with infinite decimal digits, binary representation has a lot more of these cases.

As a side note, this is why COBOL offers decimal datatypes -- it was meant for business calculations, and you can't have money calculations come up with slightly different results than expected... like, in our example, $0.40 should not turn into an ugly mess

Let's approach it from a different direction: enter your binary value into the tool, and observe that its translated to "0.11139256". Now, enter your other value, "0.111392558" into the tool, and observe that it produced the exact same binary value... you're already in a range where your float doesn't have enough bits to distinguish between the two. So all the numbers you are providing are leading into the same binary representation... so they are all identical.

Comment: So, I should always retrieve the original value if I store a float with 9 decimal places?

Comment: Floating point and strings is generally a complicated situation. If you look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars, you'll find a note stating "The guarantee that std::from_chars can recover every floating-point value formatted by std::to_chars exactly is only provided if both functions are from the same implementation", which hints at such difficulties. When it comes to floating point, expect some losses unless you can afford to save the binary or use an implementation such as the above. But, in general, storing "enough digits" is as close as it gets

Comment: Still, you can also take a look at "std::numeric_limits::digits10" to learn about the number of digits for your floats: not every float is 32 bit, and not every float is IEEE754.But, from a practical perspective, that might be overkill -- it might just be me, but I generally don't worry too much about platforms I'll never see.

Comment: I think everyone understands that continuing fractions, represented in different number bases, differ.  This question seems to be about rounding, not truncation.